Is $\sigma$-weakly closed ideals are WOT closed?
I was reading this Proposition 3.12 in Takesaki's Operator Algebras I. Here it is proved that a $\sigma$-weakly closed (left) ideal is of the form $\mathscr{M}e$ for a unique projection $e$. A similar result is proved in Kadison Ringrose Vol2 in Theorem 6.8.8 where they proved a WOT closed ideal has this form.
Now any WOT closed set is $\sigma$-closed but is it the case that $\sigma$-weakly closed (left or right) ideals are WOT-closed? Or, the statement in Kadison-Ringrose is a corollary to that of Takesaki's?

It is not hard to show that $Me$ is WOT closed, so that answers your question. (Alternatively, use Kaplansky’s density theorem.)

(The reason sometimes people prefer to use $\sigma$-weak topology instead of WOT is that the former is internal to the algebra, while the latter depends on the representation. But while the two do not coincide in general, they are effectively the same for nearly all practical purposes.)

@DavidGao I could use the Kaplansky's density theorem on $Me$, but it is not $*$-closed in general. Right?

@DavidGao I can see that
$={∣∈}={∈∣=0 \text{ for all }  \in e\mathcal{H}^\perp}=\bigcap_{∈\mathcal{H}^{\perp}}{∈∣⟨,⟩=0}$
which is WOT closed. Is this right?

Oh, you’re dealing with left ideals instead of two-sided ideals. In that case ignore the Kaplansky’s density comment. You can still use Kaplansky’s density, but that’s more trouble than its worth. Just use $Me$ is WOT closed.

The final equality should be $\bigcap_{\eta \in eH^\perp, \xi \in H} {y \in M: \langle y\eta, \xi\rangle = 0}$. Otherwise this is correct.
